# Finding the independence of one random variable based on conditional probability.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, statistical-inference, independence

$f_E(e) = f_{E\mid G,A}(e\mid g,a)$ since they are both $1/3$. I also noted that the probability of any $g,a$ in the respective sample space is $1/6$ which covers the full sample space since g x a = 6 (Hopefully I did this right). I am having issues with this and think that I may be mixing values up or approaching this in the wrong way.

Would there be another way of going about this (without obviously manually writing the whole sample space) in order to confirm that this holds true?  [stat inferential question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edl3X.png)

> Suppose $f_{\text{Education | Gender, Age}}(e\mid g,a) = 1/3$ for each $e$ for any $g\in\{0,1\}$ and $a\in\{20,30,40\}$, and that $f_{\text{Gender,Age}}(g,a)=1/6$ for any such $g, a$.  Are Education and (Gender, Age) independent?

Comment: It would help if you gave background.  e,g,a and f(e), f(e|g,a) need to be defined.

Comment: Education (e) can be 3 random variables {5, 10, 20}, Gender (g) can be 2 RVs {0,1}, Age (a) can be 3 RVs {20,30,40}. I do not understand how to use LaTeX but f has the subscripts in capital letters as what is show in the parenthesis so f(e) = f_E(e) and so on

Comment: @AlexanderMartinez That is how to use subscripts in LaTeX. On this site, just wrap your maths in dollar delimiters: `$f_E(e)$` becomes $f_E(e)$. If the subscript is more than one letter, wrap that in parenthesis. `$f_{E,G}(e,g)$` becomes $f_{E,G}(e,g)$. Also to display parenthesis put a backslash before each: `$\{x\}$` becomes $\{x\}$.

Comment: If f(e)=f(e|g,a) for all possible values of e, g, a then e is independent of g and a, by definition.

Comment: apparently related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197684/finding-the-the-joint-pmf

Comment: I am so incredibly thankful for how helpful everyone in this thread has been. Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would there be another way of going about this (without obviously manually writing the whole sample space) in order to confirm that this holds true?

Nope, that is the best way to go.

Since for all six combinations of gender and age, the probability mass functions (for any $e$) are constant, thence we can simply calculate:

$$\begin{align}f_{\text{Education}}(e) &= \sum_{\langle g,a\rangle\in\{0,1\}{\times}\{20,30,40\}}f_{\text{Education|Gender,Age}}(e\mid g,a)\,f_{\text{Gender,Age}}(g,a)\\&=6\cdot(1/3)\cdot(1/6)\\&=1/3\\&=f_{\text{Education|Gender,Age}}(e\mid g,a)\end{align}$$

As this holds for any $e$ and all $g,a$ (as provided), this establishes the
independence of Education from (Gender, Age).